# Having trouble with Regexp, extracting by pattern from massive string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have massive string, below is just an example:

```
'10029885_96945_S  example.com 86.241.75.49 - - [01/Dec/2016:09:00:00 +0000] "GET /_t.gif?pid=12641&evt=25&st=placement&s=0&c=24&t=video&l=dmlkZW8&d=&ord=1480582745631 HTTP/1.1" 200 657 "http://www.lefigaro.fr/flash-actu/2016/11/30/97001-20161130FILWWW00291-paul-guers-et-sa-femme-retrouves-morts-a-leur-domicile.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" 10.182.9.228:80'
```

Using Regexp i need to have string like this:

```
GET /_t.gif?pid=12641&evt=25&st=placement&s=0&c=24&t=video&l=dmlkZW8&d=&ord=1480582745631
```

I have not much understanding how the Regexp pattern should be constracted, so any help, comments, tips, tutorials much appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You are parsing an HTTPd log. I'd recommend researching how to parse it. There are gems, and regular expressions available so you don't have to write your own code, instead you can take advantage of existing wheels. Search for "ruby parse httpd log" and "httpd log regular expression" and you'll find useful information.

Comment: It's not enough to give an example of a string you wish to extract. You need to identify the characteristics of the string that one would use to extract it. For example, must the string begin with `GET`? Must it end with `&ord=` followed by a non-negative integer with a given number of digits? Must the string end at the end of a line? End of a string?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure of the goal, but this really simple regex returns the correct result for your sample.

```
/GET \S*/
```

to handle more verbs you could use:

```
/(GET|PUT|PATCH|DELETE) \S*/
```

A really awesome resource for regex work is: 
http://rubular.com/

I highly recommend testing out anything complex there.

Comment: I highly recommend testing your second regex with the link you provided ;)

Comment: Yikes; Snagged by my own advice! Lost a set of parens. Fixed.

Comment: You don't need parens  around each word. You'd get 2 groups with `GET` otherwise.

Comment: Yup, paranoid paren syndrome.